# Downloading exe.config file from clickonce with WebClient class problem

Tags: c#, iis, clickonce, webclient

I'm downloading from clickonce server new versions of files by my autoupdater.  However, any time downloading cycle comes over MyApplication.exe.config file on the server `webClient.DownloadFile(remoteFile, localFile`) throws a `System.Net.WebException` with code 500 (internal server error or something like that).  At the same time application event log renders few entries from asp.net, like

1. failed to initialize AppDomain /LM/W3SVC/1/ROOT
   Exception: System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException
2. asp.net process id doesn't have permission to access GAC
3. aspnet_wp.exe stoped.

But the cycle continues successfully for all other files.

Does it somehow figures that it is config file for a web server, since asp.net is .NET framework itself and "knows" about .config file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIS, by default, does not serve up `.config` files.  Do you have access to the IIS configuration on the ClickOnce server, so that you can see if `.config` is disallowed in the request filtering module?

In IIS 7, it's in Request Filtering in the IIS section.  I'll see if I can find where that's configured in IIS 6.

Comment: Yes, I do have an access to my server.  Let me see, if I can find that filter.  Thanx

Comment: Is that in ISAPI filters somewhere?

Answer (score 4):

As was already mentioned in the other answer, IIS will not serve .config files.  Where my answer is different is the proposed work around: ClickOnce has an option to use .deploy files, where all your file names have a .deploy extension appended to them.  This neatly gets around the IIS config transfer problem.

Comment: I've just thought about it, but got involved into searching for config files.  Using deploy file extension might be an option.  Thanx